# React Router: How to render different Components with different parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router, frontend, react-router-v4

Is it possible to have routes with different parameters and render different components based on the parameters?

For an example can I do:

```
<Route path="/SamePath/:param1" component={Component1} />
<Route path="/SamePath/:param2" component={Component2} />
```

Comment: Check out the [react-router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params), you can have the component being rendered read from the `:param1` variable and decide what to render from there.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to have a the same route structure but render different components based on the value of the param, then you could try using **render** to decide which component to render based on the value of the param:

```
<Route path="/SamePath/:param1" render={ (props) => {

  if (props.match.params.param1 == 'something') {
    return <Component1 { ...props } />
  } else {
    return <Component2 { ...props } />
  }

} />
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is for lets say only two routes that will differ instead of using the capturing : just type in the name Eg.( samePath/organges samePath/apples) of the route if thats not the case and you want to capture a variarty range of to render differnt components you could use the regex routes feature of react router 4.. but that is much more complicated

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I created a dictionary mapping possible values of the parameter to the desired component, and created `<Route>`s based on this dictionary.

```
<Switch>{
    [{
        ['param1']: Component1,
        ['param2']: Component2,
    }].forEach((component, param) =>
        <Route
            component={component}
            exact
            path={`/path/with/${param}`}
        />
    )
}</Switch>
```

This will produces individual `<Route>`s for each path variation you wish to match. It will render different components for each route and, to me, seems in keeping with React-Router v4's dynamic routing ethos.

I encountered a problem: I couldn't access the value of the param via the `match` property passed to the rendered child. The Route matches against a specific path string (e.g. '/path/with/paramValue1`) and not against a route descriptor with a parameter (e.g. '/path/with/:param'). This means the`match.params` dictionary passed to the child will not contain any keys or values. If you don't need the params in your child, this method will work fine. I wanted to inspect the param in the child so I had to look for a different method.